# Singing and dancing were among his many talents. (prepositional phrase: adjectival or adverbial)

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Singing and dancing were among his many talents.

'among his many talents' is a prepositional phrase and

I wonder what prepositional phrase it is: adjectival or adverbial.

If it is adverbial, then I think the verb 'were' implies 'existence'. For example, in "he is in the room." the verb 'is' means 'exists' and 'in the room' modifies the verb 'is' as an adverbial phrase.

Comment: Personally, I don't buy an adverbial phrase modifying a be verb. For me, the verb must not be stative to take an adverbial prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Lambie Thx.  Do you think it's closer to an 'adjectival' usage?

Comment: Its function is not modifier (e.g. adverbial) but that of **complement** of the verb "be". We know it's a complement because if it's dropped the sentence becomes ungrammatical. It means that he had many talents including singing and dancing.

Comment: @BillJ I am a boy. I am happy. Here, 'a boy' and 'happy' are called complements(subjective complements); I think if it's not an adverbial function and but a function as a complement, it could be or is closer to an adjectival phrase. Is there a way to defferentiate the subjective complement from a verb be complement?

Comment: "A boy" is a noun phrase and "happy" is an adjective phrase; those are their categories. Functionally, both complements are called the **ascriptive** use of "be" because they denote a property that is **ascribed** to the referent of "I" (the 'predicand').